# Manually change cron file without crontab -e

Tags: cron

I'm developing a web page to change cron programmatically. My problem was that I can't change cron jobs because `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` needs `crontab -e` to install the cron job.

I give you the solution right below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This solution was tested on: Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 9, both on PC and ARM (raspberry pi3 and udoo neo).

I found the solution in a [doc from 1999](https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/1999-April/msg00175.html) (thanks redhat). [Cron (Vixie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Modern_versions) was released on 1993.

It says that you need to add your cron jobs to `/etc/crontab`, but It's better to add your crontab jobs to `/etc/cron.d/username`. Change `username` by your user (root, john, etc.) and It's done!.

**IMPORTANT TIP**

In `/etc/crontab/` or `/etc/cron.d/username` you must set the username that run this cronjob inside the file. Example syntax:

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello World"
```

This is a pretty easy example but you should take care of syntax. For a few more examples and information about cron and their periodicity you can check Ubuntu's [cron manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Crontab_Lines).